# process of deployment independent websites from SaaS Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, host, saas

first of all I'm not sure how I can explain myself since I'm not native English speaker but please bear with me in the following scenario: I have a lot of customers where they need a simple blog website with their own domain name, instead of me registering on host service provider and deploying that blog website manually I'm looking for a better automated solution for example it would make a lot of sense if they use my own platform so after a successful registration/payment on my platform their website is deployed independently on private server instance (with their own specific config) ... Im not really looking for an answer on exactly how to implement that but what that process is called (the deployment part) or under what category should I dig to learn more. your advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple approaches to solve the problem.

However, simple one will be using AWS SDK to create EC2 instances with `Bitnami wordpress image`.

You can trigger the API with parameters which will auto-install wordpress, configure dns and other stuff and provide the ready to use website within seconds.